# How to filter a list of objects retrieved from a HTTP GET request?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular app, I'm retrieving a list of `Offer` objects using a HTTP GET Request.

Here is my interface:

```
export interface IOffer {
    id: number;
    managerId: number;
    jobId: number;
    employeeId: number;
}
```

The below code is in my service:

```
this._offerService.getOffers().subscribe(
    myOffers => {
        this.myOffers = myOffers;
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
);
```

The above code populate `myOffers` with **all** Offer objects.

Now, I need to filter those offers based a local variable - `empId`.

So I want to store an Offer if the employeeId matches my `empId`.

Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: `this.myOffers = myOffers.filter(_ => _.employeeId === empId)`

Comment: this.filteredOffers = this.myOffers.filter(offer => offer.empId == empId);
Use filter methods to get your desired objects of array in another variable like this. Filter method on array objects return an array of objects based containing objects that have values as your passed parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) rxjs method.

```
this._offerService.getOffers()
.pipe(filter(value => value.id ===empId))
```